# How to PInvoke a C++ Function that returns an interface

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

I'm trying to find out how to get the ISubmitter returned from C++ and use it on the C# side.

**This is the header (*.h):**

```
class ISubmitter : public ISubRefCounter
{
public:
    virtual ~ISubmitter() {}

    virtual Sett::MAIN::SUBERRORS Prepare( const Sett::MAIN::IDoc *pDoc, const char *aName = NULL, uint32_t aVal = 255 ) = 0;

    virtual SUBERRORS Send( eTTYPE aPType = Announce ) = 0;

    virtual ISender * CreateSenderInstance( INFO *info ) = 0;
}

class ISubRefCounter
{
public:
    virtual ~ISubRefCounter() {};

    virtual int32_t AddRef()  = 0;

    virtual int32_t Release() = 0;
};

#if defined (__cplusplus)
    extern "C" {
#endif
        ISubmitter* SUB_API_CALL GetSubmitterInterface( void );
#if defined (__cplusplus)
    }
#endif
```

**I've implemented on C# like this:**

```
public interface ISubmitter : ISubRefCounter
{
    SUBERRORS Prepare(ref IDoc pDoc, string aName = "", uint aVal = 255 );

    SUBERRORS Send(eTTYPE aPType = eTTYPE.Announce);

    ISender CreateSenderInstance(ref INFO info);
}

public interface ISubRefCounter
{
    int AddRef();

    int Release();
}
```

And also tried with a single interface, without implementing *ISubRefCounter* but instead embedding everything in *ISubmitter*, like so:

```
public interface ISubmitter
{
    SUBERRORS Prepare(ref IDoc pDoc, string aName = "", uint aVal = 255 );

    SUBERRORS Send(eTTYPE aPType = eTTYPE.Announce);

    ISender CreateSenderInstance(ref INFO info);

    int AddRef();

    int Release();
}
```

**C# dll import:**

```
[DllImport("SettSubmitter.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern ref ISubmitter GetSubmitterInterface();
```

**When calling *GetSubmitterInterface()* I get:**

> 'Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type
>   combination.'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `ref IDoc` looks wrong, as is `ref ISubmitter` on the return type. Remove the `ref` in both those places. I guess there will be other problems, but this is where to start.

Comment: It might be a lo easier to write a C++/CLI wrapper for it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thank you. I removed both refs and it throw 'Exception from HRESULT: 0xF6C71BA0'

Comment: @nvoigt I agree but I'm curious how to make this work

Comment: You can't do this directly, you need to write c functions for every method on your class, you need to store your c++ object in c# as a `NativePtr` you can't cast it to your c# interface type. I'd recommend using SWIG to do the heavy lifting for you

Comment: @AlanBirtles I think you're right. I was hoping that I could do this somehow. No worries, thank you.

Comment: @Alan Don't think so. If you make it a COM interface then it should be fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes that's another option, though if you're going down the Microsoft only route might use CLI which is probably simpler

Comment: @tweellt That error is thrown when you call `GetSubmitterInterface`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, when I call GetSubmitterInterface() I get that error. If I leave the ref I get 'Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination'

Comment: You probably need to make it a COM interface. However, C++/CLI will indeed be simpler.

Comment: Since this question is unlikely to have an accepted answer, just to close this topic, I did implement C++/CLI wrapper and works as expected. Thank you